# Broken pip3 and easy_install3: DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, pip

My `pip3` seems to be broken:

```
$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2708, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6
```

I tried to fix it by reinstalling `pip3` with `easy_install3`, but `easy_install3` is also broken:

```
$ sudo easy_install3 --upgrade pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2708, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: distribute==0.6.24dev-r0
```

Reinstalling pip3 from apt did not help either.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
$ sudo apt-get install --fix-missing -t testing python3-pip
```

I am running Debian 7 (stable). I have Python 3.4.2 installed from the testing repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to download and run two scripts, [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and [`ez_setup.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py)

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
sudo python3 ez_setup.py
```

Those fixed both pip3 and easy_install3.

Comment: As documented in the script `get-pip.py`, the script contains 'a base85 encoding of a zip file, this zip file contains an entire copy of pip.'... Despite being documented, I won't be using this as I believe it is insane to execute this script using `sudo`

Answer (score 10):

Probably the easiest way to get everything working again is to download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), then run

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

This will upgrade `pip` to the latest version (currently 6.1.1) and update `setuptools` as well.

Comment: ``pip3 --version`` works now, but it looks like I can't install packages. http://pastebin.com/KxFmvtn6

Comment: @felixbade what does `sudo pip3 --version` return?

Comment: pip 6.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)

Comment: Got it! ``get-pip.py`` did not update ``setuptools``, but I found [ez_setup.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py) from the same website. Then I ran ``sudo python3 ez_setup.py``