# Python pip installation in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am new to Ubuntu  and was trying to install pip using get-pip.py , when I received this message.

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
```

But when I enter `pip -V`, I receive an error saying :

```
The 'pip==7.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

[Complete error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhVVa.jpg)

I was trying to install new packages using `pip install <packagename>` but this command gives the same error as previous .

Comment: How did you install exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest installing pip using the package manager. Open up a terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

That *should* install the [pip](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-pip) ubunutu package.

Comment: Also, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734436/pip-broken-reinstall-doesnt-work-ec2) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288404/broken-pip3-and-easy-install3-distributionnotfound)

Comment: The apt-get version is always a few releases behind and usually slower to fix any bugs, installing with get-pip should work so there is something else going on. I have used get-pip on Ubuntu numerous times without any issue

Comment: @PadraicCunningham After you install pip properly with the package manager, you can then update pip using pip if you really need to.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be installing pip for the default python installation, neither from the package manager nor using `get-pip.py`. So you can never use it to break the system python.

Instead always use `virtualenv` (created from the default/system python or from a newer version), activate and use `pip` in that environment.