# pip3 not working after updating pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I followed the suggestion by pip on my `Ubuntu 16.04` machine

```
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

to upgrade my pip. And now when I run pip3 it shows me the following error:

```
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==8.1.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

It looks like pip3 is not updated along with the pip. 
I tried upgrading by the pip3 by running `sudo python3 get-pip.py` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288404/broken-pip3-and-easy-install3-distributionnotfound) thread. But it showed me the following error

`python3: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

How should I fix this?

Comment: Is that a unix/linux machine?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288404/broken-pip3-and-easy-install3-distributionnotfound?

Comment: @sobex I'm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The last error you got means that you didn't give the right path to the file. You'll need to give the full path to the `get-pip.py` file.